# Como encuentro subcadenas de una cadena de texto y las mustro por pantalla

Tags: python, string

Hola buenas necesito hacer el siguiente programa: "implementa una aplicación que tome un texto y devuelva las subcadenas que comienzan y acaban igual que una cadena indicada."
Seria algo asi:

```
Entrada: "La casa tenía una cama y era bastante cara en su categoría."
Entrada del buscador: "casa"
Salida: casa, cara, cama, categoría
```

Todo esto con strings de momento he conseguido hacer esto pero no me pasa de la primera palabra con la que coincide

```
chain = input("introduce un texto: ")
indexinput = input("introduce la primera parte de la palabra que quieres buscar: ")
indexinput2 = input("introduce la segunda parte de la palabra que quieres buscar: ")
for x in chain:
    index = chain.index(indexinput)
    index2 = chain.index(indexinput2)
    subchain = chain[index:index2 + 2]
    print(subchain)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: `salida = [x for x in entrada.split() if x[0] == palabra[0] and x[-1] == palabra[-1]]`

Comment: No entiendo me lo puedes explicar como quedaria y eso? No se a que te refieres

Comment: @CandidMoe, en ese caso no devolvería "categoría" porque termina con `.`. Pregunta, ¿Qué es más rápido utilizar slices o `startswith` y `endswith`?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato. Dado que solo comparo un caracter me basta con usar índices, evitando una llamada a función. Hice un poco de trampa con "categoría": le saque el punto final a la entrada. Se puedo manejar, pero ya no sale en una línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Como es probable que la cadena tenga multiples caracteres para separar las palabras, por ejemplo `,`, `.`, `;`, Espacio en blanco ( ), etc... podrías utilizar `split` de la librería `re` (Regex) y una comprensión de listas:

Ejemplo sin los `input` para mostrar el funcionamiento, tendrías que agregar los `input`:

```
import re

cadena = 'La casa tenía una cama y era bastante cara en su categoría.'
palabra = 'casa'
salida = [p for p in re.split(' |\.', cadena) if p.startswith(palabra[0]) and p.endswith(palabra[-1])]
print(salida)
```

Esto imprime:

```
['casa', 'cama', 'cara', 'categoría']
```

Edición: `re.split()` genera una lista de palabras y con una comprensión de listas revisamos cuales de esas palabras inician con la misma letra que la palabra seleccionada y termina con la misma letra de la palabra seleccionada.

Comment: si no es mucha molestia me podrias decir que hace exactamente todo el proceso de la variable salida porque no lo acabo de entender al 100%

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Comment: He editado tu respuesta para añadir comentarios explicativos dime si esta bien porfavor

Answer (score 1):

Otra con expresiones regulares:

```
import re

cadena = 'La casa tenía una cama y era bastante cara en su categoría.'
palabra = 'casa'

primera = palabra[0]
ultima = palabra[-1]
patron = re.compile(f"\s({primera}\S*{ultima})[\s|[\.,:]")
salida = patron.findall(cadena)
print(salida) # => ['casa', 'cama', 'cara', 'categoría']
```

El método `findall()` nos viene de perillas, pues encuentra todas las ocurrencias del patrón buscado y las devuelve en una cadena.

La idea es armar un patrón que reconozca palabras que empiezan y terminan con lo pedido: la primera y última letra coincidan.

Con un f-string armamos el patron

```
primera = palabra[0]
ultima = palabra[-1]
patron = re.compile(f"\s({primera}\S*{ultima})[\s\.,:]")
```

El patrón resultante es `\s(c\S*a)[\s\.,:]`: un espacio, seguido de "c", luego cero o más cosas que no son espacio, terminado con una "a". Se reconoce el término de la palabra por un espacio en blanco, un punto, una coma o dos puntos.

Los paréntesis en la expresión regular marcan un *grupo de captura*: el texto reconocido por esa parte será almacenado en una lista.

Con esto solo queda llamar y obtener la lista:

```
salida = patron.findall(cadena)
```